# Geocoding query returns results 10000km away :-/

Tags: here-api

i just got some strange results for a geocoding query sent to the API.

> http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?prox=-42.48014%2C-73.762414%2C10000&searchtext=al%20%2C%20Castro%20%2C%20Castro%20%2C%20cl&app_id=XXX&app_code=XXX&gen=3&maxresult=100&language=es

so the location is properly found on http://here.com/-42.4801399,-73.7604828,17,0,0,normal.day

but the API-response includes totally different information.

`{"Response":{"MetaInfo":{"Timestamp":"2014-08-13T06:41:28.518+0000"},"View":[{"_type":"SearchResultsViewType","ViewId":0,"Result":[{"Relevance":0.9,"Distance":1.00628071E7,"MatchLevel":"street","MatchQuality":{"State":0.71,"City":0.89,"Street":[0.85]},"Location":{"LocationId":"NT_zSCm7jYDz+HltoMoaXf6NA","LocationType":"point","DisplayPosition":{"Latitude":36.7596283,"Longitude":-121.7462616},"NavigationPosition":[{"Latitude":36.7596283,"Longitude":-121.7462616}],"MapView":{"TopLeft":{"Latitude":36.7616081,"Longitude":-121.7468719},"BottomRight":{"Latitude":36.7576599,"Longitude":-121.7456436}},"Address":{"Label":"Castro St, Castroville, CA 95012, Estados Unidos","Country":"USA","State":"CA","County":"Monterey","City":"Castroville","Street":"Castro St","PostalCode":"95012","AdditionalData":[{"value":"Estados Unidos","key":"CountryName"},{"value":"California","key":"StateName"}]}}}]}]}}`

Could you give me a helping hand to solve this?

Best regards,
Matthias :)

Comment: Do you maybe have latitude and longitude the wrong way round in the search?

Comment: Hi @JohnBarça .. the lat/lng is correct, as the wanted location is found correctly on here.com as well as google maps / bing ..

Answer (score 0):

The question is 10000km away from **where**? The geocoder request you are making is effectively:

> Find me somewhere in the **world** with  *"al, Castro,Castro, cl"* somewhere in the
>   address

The result obtained happens to be in San Francisco, California which may or may not be 10000km from anywhere, but just happens to be the best fit result to the request.

What you probably want is something like:

> Find me somewhere in **Chile** with  *"Castro"* somewhere in the
>   address

[http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=Castro&app_id=XXX&app_code=XXX&country=Chile](http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=Castro&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=3&country=Chile)

or

> Find me somewhere within a specified rectangle  **San Francisco, California** with  *"Castro"* somewhere in the
>   address

[http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=Castro&app_id=XXXX&app_code=XXXX&mapview=37.7983366,-122.4006509;37.7904096,-122.3916387](http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=Castro&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&mapview=37.7983366,-122.4006509;37.7904096,-122.3916387)

These biasing effects can be obtained using the `mapview`, `country` and `countryfocus` parameters as specified in the [API Reference](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-geocode.html)